# getting 169.x.x.x IP for WiFi and have no internet connection. Mac OSX 10.7 Lion (Server Packages installed)

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, xserve, osx-lion

After installing the new Developer Preview for Mac OSX 10.7 Lion and additionally installing the included server packages I have problems connecting my Mac Book Pro 2,2 via WiFi.
i think the error lies somewhere in the dhcp setup. 
Connection over Ethernet is working and I´m going nuts right now.
i`ve tried several setups for the dhcp ... and also tried disabling dhcp (because I don´t need it) in the server settings. but no chance I´m getting this 169.x IP and no Internet connection. 
Also googling this brought no succes.
I erased my wifi settings, installed and configured it again. I tried to manually define my IP Adress but no success.
Any Help out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 169.x.x.x IP range is a range set aside for DHCP communications.  If you are ending up with an address in this range it means that your computer has failed to get an address using normal DHCP methods and the computer has set this address in an attempt to communicate with the DHCP server in a more direct way.

So yes, it seems that DHCP is to blame.

If you can't communicate with even a manually assigned IP address, and you are certain that IP and it's associated netmask are 100% correct, then the issue may lie somewhere in the network interface drivers or the wireless encryption setup.

Comment: ok thanx for the rapid answer :) i think i try to reinstall mac osx lion without the server packages because I only wanted to "try it out". but thx anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say that the computer has failed to get an address from DHCP if it ends up with a 169 address. I am working on a PC network that uses the 169 addresses for DHCP and it works fine. That is, until a Mac tries to connect. The Mac will not accept a 169 address and refuses to join the network. Can this be overcome?